# Make autotools add --std=c11 to CFLAGS

Tags: c, autotools, c11

There is no [mention](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/C-Compiler.html#C-Compiler) of a `AC_PROG_CC_C11` analogue to `AC_PROG_CC_C99`.

How can I get my autotools project to put `--std=c11` into `CFLAGS`?

Comment: note: [future](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf.git;a=blob_plain;f=lib/autoconf/c.m4;hb=refs/heads/master) autoconf releases (still in git repo) will integrate C11 testing with `AC_PROG_CC`, setting `ac_cv_prog_cc_c11` and `ac_prog_cc_stdc` accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't the title and body of the question be corrected to say "-std=c11", not "--std=C11"?  I assume the author cares about the option accepted by GCC, Clang, Intel and other compilers.

Comment: I've extracted the C11 probe to a m4/c11.m4 at https://github.com/rurban/safeclib/commit/e57c5e2df3073be8ecc682daa1e9f6856f72415b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most simply by putting

```
CFLAGS+=" -std=c11"
```

into your `configure.ac` (in addition to `AC_PROG_CC`). `configure.ac` is a template for a shell script, so you can simply put shell code in it. In fact, all the `AC_FOO_BAR` m4 macros expand to shell code themselves.

Caveat: This will not check whether your compiler actually supports the `-std=c11` flag. If you want to check for that, you can use use [`AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_check_compile_flag.html) from the [autoconf archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/):

```
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c11], [
  CFLAGS+=" -std=c11"
], [
  echo "C compiler cannot compile C11 code"
  exit -1
])
```

...although simply waiting until something fails in the compilation also works, I suppose. The error message will be nicer this way, though.

Comment: The AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG does not work.  (I also tried changing `-std=c11` to `--std=c11`.)  The error is `./configure: line 12232: syntax error near unexpected token '-std=c11,'
./configure: line 12232: 'AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-std=c11,'
`.  I don't know what's eating the square brackets.

Comment: You need to install the autoconf archive for it to work (only on the machine where you run `autoreconf`, not everywhere the package should be compiled). Most Linux distributions have packages for it, and there's a FreeBSD port. Not sure about MacOS X and other BSDs.

Comment: Or you can pick the `ax_check_compile_flag.m4` file out of the tarball behind the link in the answer and dump it into your `m4` directory. It doesn't seem to have any dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand why this works. `+=` is a Bash extension, isn't it? When I run `foo+=bar` in Dash it rejects it with a syntax error, but yet when I run a configure script with this in it explicitly in Dash, it works. What gives?

Comment: You should never use `+=` for portability. Instead: `CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -std=c11"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_CHECK_STDC],
[AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=gnu11],
    [AX_APPEND_FLAG([-std=gnu11])],
    [AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c11],
        [AX_APPEND_FLAG([-std=c11])],
        [AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c99],
            [AX_APPEND_FLAG([-std=c99])],
            [AC_MSG_ERROR([C compiled does not support at least C99!])])
        ])
    ])
])
```

Output:

```
checking whether C compiler accepts -std=gnu11... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -std=c11... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -std=c99... yes
```

(when building using shit Microchip xc16 PIC compiler)